# Torsion homologically trivial cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, hodge-theory, intersection-theory

Is there an example of a smooth projective variety $X$ over the complex numbers, such that

$$\ker(\text{CH}^2(X)\to H^4(X,\mathbf{Z}(2))$$

is **not** torsion?

Comment: quintic threefold

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reference I could look into?

Comment: Yes: "The Griffiths group of a general Calabi-Yau threefold is not finitely generated" by Claire Voisin

Comment: Actually, "almost all" (smooth projective) surfaces give examples. In particular, abelian surfaces do.

Comment: For *any* surface admitting a nonzero holomorphic 2-form, the kernel is a huge $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space. I recommend Voisin's book to get some familiarity with this subject.